# strange behavior of focusout handler

Tags: jquery, onclick, focusout

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txt1").focusout(function () { $("#lbl1").text("aaaa"); });
        $('#btn1').click(function (){ alert("clicked"); });
    });
</script>

<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

I run my code, and do the following steps: 
1. press with mouse inside txt1
2. press with mouse on btn1
The alert message does not appear. It appears only if I click the button again.
This happens only when I change lbl1's text, on focusout. 
Why does the text changing cause the click event not to be fired?

Comment: Did you tried: `$('#btn1').click(function (){ $("#txt1").blur(); alert("clicked"); });`

Comment: This solve your problem: `$('#btn1').click(function (){ alert("clicked"); }).click();` but I don't think it's good idea....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your script is not binding the click event to the button. Because it has the attribute `runat=server`. So it will change the id of the elements at the time of rendering. you should either use a class name or `clientID` instead of id.

using class name,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".txt1").focusout(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".lbl1").text("aaaa");
    });
    $('.btn1').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("clicked");
    });
});
</script>

<asp:Label ID="lbl1" CssClass="lbl1"  runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" CssClass="txt1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btn1" CssClass="btn1" runat="server" />
```

**Edit**

The problem is with the position of label. Please check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/97/)

Comment: that's not the story. I have ClientIDMode="Static" on the whole page.

Comment: see the fiddle, the problem is with the changing of position. http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/97/

Comment: @keyla_kl did you check the fiddle?

Comment: I did check the fiddle. I'm sorry, I don't understand... what do you mean "changing of position"?

Comment: @keyla_kl does that fiddle have any problem?

Comment: Oh, now I get it! Your answer is simple and true: the position of the button changed, so the click wasn't on the button! Thanks. Please update your answer so that I will accept it.